# Why isn't the user-define variable working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a subquery in an if statement.
If I do the following it works

```
SELECT `Currency`, IF((SELECT `id` FROM `upload_currency` WHERE `CurrencyText`=`Currency`) > 0,(SELECT `id` FROM `upload_currency` WHERE `CurrencyText`=`Currency`),1) FROM `upload_salesinvoice`
```

and I get the output
1,1,USD 3,1,EUR 2,1,1,1 which is correct

However if I try to make my query more efficient like this, it gives me all 1's instead.

```
SELECT `Currency`, IF(@val:=(SELECT `id` FROM `upload_currency` WHERE `CurrencyText`=`Currency`) > 0,@val,1) FROM `upload_salesinvoice`
```

I will explain a bit more I have a table called upload_currency and in this table I have this layout

id 1, CurrencyText GBP

id 2, CurrencyText EUR

id 3, CurrencyText USD

So my subselect should return 1 for GBP, or 1 for an empty string, 2 for EUR and 3 for USD, but the second query is failing and giving me all 1's

So it looks like my user-defined variable is failing for some reason.

Comment: Note that using the variable this way shouldn't actually make your query any more efficient.  The optimizer *should* realize that the repeated subquery is repeated... and *should* reuse the value implicitly, not executing the subquery twice.

Comment: I didn't know that, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your query is not working is that you are assigning the value of the comparison to your variable; for MySQL, the assignment will read like

```
@val:=((SELECT `id` FROM `upload_currency` WHERE `CurrencyText`=`Currency`) > 0)
```

which is either 1 or 0, not the `id`. So you will have to add the parentheses and use

```
IF( (@val:=(SELECT `id` FROM `upload_currency` WHERE `CurrencyText`=`Currency`)) 
    > 0, @val, 1)
```

That being said: I think what you are trying to do in a very complicated way is actually simply a `left join`:

```
select u.currency, coalesce(c.id,1) 
from upload_salesinvoice u
left join upload_currency c 
on c.CurrencyText=u.Currency
```

It will be faster too.

Comment: Yes I was just getting a 1 back for every answer. Thanks your answer works. Those pesky little brackets are important. To answer your question as to why I am not using the left join is that the query I have shown is part of a bigger insert select query where a left join wouldn't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the mysql manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement ...

**EDITED :**

```
 SELECT `Currency`, @val := (
   SELECT `id` FROM `upload_currency` 
   WHERE `CurrencyText`=`Currency`
 ), 
 IF(@val > 0,@val,1) FROM `upload_salesinvoice`;
```

Comment: This won't work as val is changing on each row. I am checking multiple rows so the val will change on every row. Your method would fix it to one val before the select. I am checking multiple rows in the upload_salesinvoice

Comment: Thanks your answer worked, but I was hoping to do it in one line, like Solarflare did. The reason for this is that I needed to put it insert select in another query as well. And with an insert select you need the same number of fields in the insert as the select. Thanks though.